# how to generate random div box in fixed position using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want is, how to show random **div** element one at a time in a fixed position without refreshing a page. Here is my code there are three **box** and i want to show one box at a time randomly and hide another box.

sorry for my bad english.

following is my code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .box{
      background-color: red;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3q8t6jd4/2/)

```
(function loop() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.box').length);
    $('.box').hide().eq(random).show();
    loop()
  }, 1000);
}());
```

Update: looping to show a random div every second

Comment: thank you **yakutsa**, but in your demo each box display in same position.

Comment: @SurendraSinghRana, I updated the codes and implemented `margin-top` attribute to each `box` class. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3q8t6jd4/1/)

Comment: thank you **yakutsa**, it's working but what about **speed** and without page refreshing.

Comment: @SurendraSinghRana, I updated my codes again and my original post. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3q8t6jd4/2/)

Comment: **Great** again Thank You **yakutsa**.